# how to query greatest ID of each value in a Sharepoint list?

Tags: 2010, caml-query, caml

I have a list with two columns (ID,Value).

I want grouped list with value columns then select greatest Id of it.

### ID | Value

1  | 101

2  | 305

3  | 102

4  | 101

5  | 305

6  | 101

Result :

### ID | Value

3  | 102

5  | 305

6  | 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just show the list you can use a view with "Group By" = "Value" and "Total" : "ID" - Maximum

But if you need this for any data processing purpose or customized showing then LINQ is best option I guess, you can use CAML Query group by but that will be no use for your purpose, so i think something like this is your best option :

```
DataTable dtList = list.Items.GetDataTable();
var grouped = from row in dtList.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row["Value"] into valueGroup
              select new { Value = valueGroup.Key, ID = valueGroup.Max(id => id["ID"]) };
```

just wanted to point one very common fact: when you use ID as a column name it will have different internal name, so id["ID"] will be different

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to convert linq to datatable?

Comment: in many ways,as here anonymous type is involved so copyToDataTable wont work,you may consider this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx).But I always use the simplest way : DataTable dtGrouped=new DataTable();dtGrouped.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));dtGrouped.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                foreach (var group in grouped)
                {
                    DataRow row = dtGrouped.NewRow();
                    row["Value"] = group.Value;
                    row["ID"] = group.ID;
                    dtGrouped.Rows.Add(row);
                }